# How to use CSS to have table cell specific border colors?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I’m trying to make an html table with blue borders all around but with one column span row or table data cell to have a red border instead of blue. I’ve looked and I cannot find an answer, I don’t want to use html I want to use CSS.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide a [mcve] so that we can see exactly what you are trying to do (i.e. so we can see what CSS you already have and the contents of the table)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a class which contains a definition to make the border red (like so):

```
.red td {
    border: red solid 1px; /*Change the 1px to some other value*/
}
```

And then, apply that class to the cell you want to change:

```
<tr class="red">
<td> some text here </td>
</tr>
```

That seems to be the best solution to your problem given the details